# Set interation in Java

Tags: java

I have a house with rooms. I am calling this house recursively to get the rooms and I will like the house name to be printed Just only once for all the rooms.

e.g.

> HouseName: City Hall - followed by the Room properties for each room.

```
   House house;
   Set<House> rooms = house.getRooms();

   //Bear in mind that all rooms have the same house name (houseName)
   for(House room:rooms){
      System.out.println(room.getHouseName()); // will be the same for all rooms
      System.out.println("Room: "); 
      System.out.println(room.getColor());
      System.out.println(room.getState()); 
      System.out.println();    
}
```

I would like to output the `houseName` only once for all rooms in the form shown below.

> Output:
>
> House Name: City Hall
>      No of Rooms: 3
>
> ---
>
> Room:
>      red
>      old
>
> Room:
>      blue
>      damaged
>
> Room:
>      white
>      Renovated

Comment: May be you want map implementation?

Comment: Why are your rooms of type `House`? And by "recursively" do you mean "iteratively"?

Comment: @ruak: Recursive means that the house calls itself and contains a houseName and a Set of rooms -Set<House> rooms

Comment: @K.Sun: Can you post the code where one of `House`'s methods calls itself? (Right now you arguably have a recursive data structure, but despite what you say, you don't actually seem to be recursing through it!)

Comment: @Nambari: I have already started using set for its benefits. (no duplications allowed). So, I really want the implementation from the Set perspective. The problem is that Set doesn't have a get (int index) method to access its indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try followings

Here is my Rooms class

```
public class Rooms {
String color;
String state;

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
}
```

Now here is my House Class

```
public class House {
String houseName;
int numberOfRooms;
Set<Rooms> rooms=new HashSet<>();

public String getHouseName() {
    return houseName;
}

public void setHouseName(String houseName) {
    this.houseName = houseName;
}

public int getNumberOfRooms() {
    return numberOfRooms;
}

public void setNumberOfRooms(int numberOfRooms) {
    this.numberOfRooms = numberOfRooms;
}

public void setRooms(Set<Rooms> rooms) {
    this.rooms = rooms;
}

public Set<Rooms> getRooms() {
    return rooms;
}

public Set<House> getHouse(){
    Set<House> houses=new HashSet<>();
    Set<Rooms> rooms=new HashSet<>();
    House h1=new House();
    Rooms r1=new Rooms();
    Rooms r2=new Rooms();

    r1.setColor("red");
    r1.setState("new");
    r2.setColor("blue");
    r2.setState("old");
    rooms.add(r1);
    rooms.add(r2);
    h1.setHouseName("Haven");
    h1.setNumberOfRooms(2);
    h1.setRooms(rooms);

    houses.add(h1);

    return houses;
}
}
```

Finally here is my main class

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[] args)  {
   House house=new House();
   Set<House> houses=house.getHouse();
    for(House h:houses){
        System.out.println("House Name: "+h.getHouseName());
        System.out.println("Number of rooms: "+h.getNumberOfRooms());
        for(Rooms r:h.getRooms()){
            System.out.println("Room color: "+r.getColor());
            System.out.println("Room state: "+r.getState());
        }
    }

  }
  }
```

Comment: Why does one house know all houses? It would be better to either have a class `Village` which contains the houses or use static members for this. But it is no good design to let one house know all houses.

Comment: @UwePlonus you can use what ever naming here

Comment: I mean the method `public Set<House> getHouse()` which is not good OO design. And thi question is basically about OO design...